# JPush-react-native local notification banner not displaying on Android

Tags: react-native, notifications

Using Jpush-react-native, Local notification does not display banner when called on android, Only vibrates and adds to the notification centre. (The default priority for android).
https://github.com/jpush/jpush-react-native

https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels#importance

OS: Mac OS Mojave
React-native 0.59.1
jpush-react-native: 2.6.6
Tested on: Huawei nova 2i, mi 9 se

How to escalate the priority of the local notification?

I can see from the Aurora docs that it is possible
"
JPushInterface.EXTRA_NOTI_PRIORITY
Support SDK 3.0.0 or later，and support rom 16 or more.
When the default is 0 and the range is -2 to 2 , other values will be ignored and defaulted.
Notification priority

```
Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
String prio = bundle.getString(JPushInterface.EXTRA_NOTI_PRIORITY);
```

https://docs.jiguang.cn/en/jpush/client/Android/android_api/
"

I have tried to add in the priority into the extra section without success.

```
JPush.addLocalNotification({
messageID: "123456789",
title: "testMe",
content: "messageValue",
extras: { priority: '2' }
})
```

Note: I can trigger the banner by enabling floating notifications through settings. But using other libraries I have been able to trigger the local notification banner without making the user modify their settings.

Thanks!